# Gate pulse is switching but drain pulse is not

Tags: transistors, mosfet

[image: schematic]

The above circuit input is a pulsed signal of 5 Vpp, 100 kHz. The required output is 100 kHz, minimum 28 V, minimum 10 A, 10% duty cycle pulse.

The switched pulse is observed at the gate but I'm not observing a switched pulse at the drain when I tried to implement in the hardware. I am also not sure about the diode connected to the gate  of the MOSFET. I connected ti after seeing a reference circuit and I'm not able to figure out what the exact purpose of it is. Is it necessary? If yes, should I connect a Zener diode or a normal P-N junction diode? Please suggest if any changes required in the circuitry to achieve the desired output.

What is the difference if I use an N-channel MOSFET or a P-channel MOSFET? Will it affect my desired output across load? If yes how? I need a constant voltage and constant current across my load.

Comment: Welcome! Please follow schematic best practices and draw all positive voltages pointing up, negative and ground pointing down. At the moment, V1 and M1 are upside down, which makes the schematic hard to read.

Comment: "Constant voltage and constant current" and "10% duty cycle" don't add up.  Did you leave something out?

Comment: Is the FET on or off (what's the voltage on the load)?  What are the high and low voltages on the gate?

Comment: Okay please ignore ..obtaining a constant voltage and constant current across the load. Just consider that I require minimum 28V across the source and minimum 10 A current across the load. Also in what cases do I not get a switching pulse across a drain but get it across Vgs. Where might be the problem